Duckdb case sensitivity with macros
I'm using DuckDB stable version and I'm having some problem, suppose I have the following macro to do some data aggregation and a numeric function
CREATE OR REPLACE MACRO FUN_AGGREGATE(
    GROUPBY_COLUMNS,
    AGGREGATED_COLUMNS
) AS TABLE (
    FROM TBL
    SELECT 
        COLUMNS(C -> (LIST_CONTAINS(GROUPBY_COLUMNS, C) OR LEN(GROUPBY_COLUMNS) = 0)), 
        FUN(COLUMNS(C -> LIST_CONTAINS(AGGREGATED_COLUMNS, C)))  
    GROUP BY ALL 
    ORDER BY ALL 
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun(x) as SUM(x);

and a sample data
CREATE TABLE sample_table (
    COL1 VARCHAR,  -- Character column 1
    COL2 VARCHAR,  -- Character column 2
    NUMCOL INTEGER     -- Numeric column (integer type)
);

INSERT INTO sample_table (COL1, COL2, NUMCOL) VALUES
('A', 'X', 1001),
('A', 'Y', 1002),
('A', 'X', 1003);

when I call it with column names in lower case I get
Binder Error: Star expression "COLUMNS(list_filter(['COL1', 'COL2', 'NUMCOL'], (C -> (list_contains(main.list_value(col1, col2), C) OR (len(main.list_value(col1, col2)) = 0)))))" resulted in an empty set of columns

with tbl as (select * from sample_table)
    from fun_aggregate([col1,col2],[numcol]);

but if I try to run it with uppercase column names I get
D with tbl as (select * from sample_table)
      from fun_aggregate([COL1,COL2],[NUMCOL]);
┌─────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│  COL1   │  COL2   │ NUMCOL │
│ varchar │ varchar │ int128 │
├─────────┼─────────┼────────┤
│ A       │ X       │   2004 │
│ A       │ Y       │   1002 │
└─────────┴─────────┴────────┘

I'm starting to learn it now, but DuckDB wasn't supposed to be case insensitive?

looks like a duckdb issue/error wrt to case sensitivity,
check the following from a session -
D
D SET preserve_identifier_case = false;
D 
D with tbl as (select * from sample_table)
      from fun_aggregate([col1,col2],[numcol]);
Binder Error: Star expression "COLUMNS(list_filter(['COL1', 'COL2', 'NUMCOL'], (C -> (list_contains(main.list_value(col1, col2), C) OR (len(main.list_value(col1, col2)) = 0)))))" resulted in an empty set of columns
D 
D 
D with tbl as (select * from sample_table)
        from fun_aggregate([COL1,COL2],[NUMCOL]);
Binder Error: Star expression "COLUMNS(list_filter(['COL1', 'COL2', 'NUMCOL'], (C -> (list_contains(main.list_value(col1, col2), C) OR (len(main.list_value(col1, col2)) = 0)))))" resulted in an empty set of columns
D 
D SET preserve_identifier_case = true;
D 
D with tbl as (select * from sample_table)
        from fun_aggregate([col1,col2],[numcol]);
Binder Error: Star expression "COLUMNS(list_filter(['COL1', 'COL2', 'NUMCOL'], (C -> (list_contains(main.list_value(col1, col2), C) OR (len(main.list_value(col1, col2)) = 0)))))" resulted in an empty set of columns
D 
D 
D with tbl as (select * from sample_table)
          from fun_aggregate([COL1,COL2],[NUMCOL]);
┌─────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│  COL1   │  COL2   │ NUMCOL │
│ varchar │ varchar │ int128 │
├─────────┼─────────┼────────┤
│ A       │ X       │   2004 │
│ A       │ Y       │   1002 │
└─────────┴─────────┴────────┘

I couldn't find any reference to this issue on the git site , so you may want to raise there.
